# PostgreSQL vs Oracle double

Tags: postgresql, oracle, migration

More of rant, than a question, but maybe someone would explain -- why PostgreSQL migration wiki [states that](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Oracle_to_Postgres_Conversion#Numeric_Types)

> FLOAT (Oracle) is REAL (Postgres) and DOUBLE is DOUBLE PRECISION

when in PostgreSQL `DOUBLE PRECISION` supports 15 significant digits, whereas in Oracle `DOUBLE` [provides 38](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/server.101/b10758/sqlqr06.htm) ?!

IMO, this is quite an omission for people planning to migrate their data to PostgreSQL.

Comment: Can you add the url to "PostgreSQL migration wiki"?

Comment: IEEE numbers are only good for 6 digits.  Use actual `NUMBER`or your design could be flawed.

Comment: @Lennart added.

Comment: If you need the precision, use `numeric` in Postgres

Answer (score 3):

The information seems to be inaccurate.

Oracle has only three numeric data types:

- `NUMBER`: binary coded decimals. Slow, but exact.
- `BINARY_FLOAT`: IEEE single precision floating point number. Fast and quite imprecise.
- `BINARY_DOUBLE`: IEEE double precision floating point number. Fast and less imprecise.

You can use `INTEGER`, `DOUBLE PRECISION`, `REAL` and `FLOAT` in Oracle, like the SQL standard demands, but you will always get a `NUMBER` (`FLOAT` is `NUMBER`, only the precision is given in binary rather than in decimal digits).

---

PostgreSQL has more numeric data types:

- `numeric` (or `decimal`, which is just another name): binary coded decimals. Exact, but very slow.

  This corresponds to Oracle's `NUMBER`.
- `real` (or `float4`): the platform's native single precision floating point numbers, usually IEEE

  This corresponds to Oracle's `BINARY_FLOAT`.
- `double precision` (or `float8`): the platform's native double precision floating point numbers, usually IEEE

  This corresponds to Oracle's `BINARY_DOUBLE`.
- `integer` (or `int4`): four-byte integers

  Oracle has nothing like that.
- `bigint` (or `int8`): eight-byte integers

  Oracle has nothing like that.

Comment: I read  the wiki article it goes back to 2008,  its a copy from another article that predates 2008.  Allot of the articles information is just out of date its had a few minor edits over the years.  It needs to be overhauled...

Comment: I just edited the coarsest inaccuracies.